# how to add background color to input text if it is a dojo datepicker?

Tags: css, colors, dojo

I can't set the background color (or border color) of an input text, if it is a dojo datepicker.
My dojo datepicker is an input text with the two additional attribute:

```
dojoType="dropdowndatepicker"
displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
```

I assume dojo has its own style, so even if I provide a style that specifies the background color, dojo overrides it.

something like this does not work:

```
<input type="text" ..other attributes.. style="width:5em;border:solid #FF0000;">
```

Any help is appriciated.

And may I just add that my dojo version is old as dirt ( will be upgraded) but currently I can't take advantage of the newer features like dijit, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo uses templates for most of their widgets. The HTML code you write (with `dojoType` attributes and stuff) is nothing more than a placeholder to configure your widget. Inline CSS applied to this HTML will be applied to the top level of your widget.

Your widget usually consists out of multiple HTML elements and so it may happend that the CSS you write inline, will not be applied to the correct element. Also, Dojo indeed uses themes (wich you usually define as a `class="themename"` on a parent tag (usually `<body>`) and most default themes of Dojo are using `!important` CSS lines for various features.

The best way is to inspect what HTML elements are created when you use a widget and to define a style on that specific element. But because the CSS attributes of the Dojo themes are using `!important`, it's recommended to be more specific than what they define. The easiest way is to add a custom classname to the `<body>` tag, for example:

```html
<body class="claro custom">

</body>
```

Then define your style like:

```css
.custom .dijitTextBox > .dijitInputField {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.custom .dijitTextBox > .dijitArrowButton {
    background: red;
}
```

I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/5bBHe/).

Comment: hi Dimitri, I do not doubt that there is truth in your answer, but I can't use anything that relies on dijit. My dojo is almost 10 years old.

Comment: That doesn't mean it doesn't apply. You must inspect the HTML code generated by Dojo for your datepicker and define your CSS on those HTML elements (not inline). You should also be more specific than the styles that are defined by Dojo. My answer is pretty generic and can be "re-used" for most web UI toolkits.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread - i think this could help you out:

[Changing default style of DOJO widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887574/changing-default-style-of-dojo-widget)

Regards

Answer (score -1):

add !important to the end of your rules:

```
<input type="text" ..other attributes.. style="width:5em !important;border:solid #FF0000 !important;">
```

This should apply stuff to the input. Please check if the element isn't replaced when dojo starts using it and if you are applying the style to the correct element.

Comment: why are you using !important if you are using inline css

Comment: Rohit Azad: beacause if there is a rule that is not inline and includes !important it will override the inline style. And if both are set to !important, the inline style will override the other style.

Comment: pr123: Can you provide a link ?